# jqGrid recreateForm on advanced search

Tags: jqgrid

Actually this is probably pretty simple, but somehow I am unable to make it work.

I have a grid that loads data from a url.  Everything works fine, except one small detail -- I have put a column picker on the table but if they have already shown the search form once, then when they change the visible columns the search form does not reflect the changes no matter how many times they close and open it.

The documentation seems to suggest that recreateForm was the solution, but it does not seem to work.

"when set to true the form is recreated every time the search dialog is activated with the new options from colModel (if they are changed)"

I launch the advanced search from a button outside the grid, if that matters.

```
function openSearch(grid)
{
    var searchParams = {
                            multipleSearch:true,
                            overlay:false, 
                            closeOnEscape:true,
                            Find:"Search",
                            closeAfterSearch:true,
                            caption:"Advanced Search",
                            searchOnEnter:true, 
                            recreateForm:true                       
                       };

    grid.jqGrid('searchGrid', searchParams);
}
```